# Google Geo Location Api Not working

Tags: google-maps

**Problem:** The geolocation service does not work and unsure why not.

**Suggestion to problem:** I have read here on stack overflow that it might be due to me running the program from my desktop and not a server. But I tried the fixes for it and it did not work. Also I ahve not added a information window as shown on the google page for this api but as far as I understand it isn't needed.

**Code:** Note this is just a extract of where problem is.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.4667,153.0333);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            alert('Section 1: Pass');
             if(navigator.geolocation) { 
             alert('Section 2: Pass');

                //Get the location
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                    alert('Section 3: Pass');
                    //Declate pos ()
                    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    mapOptions.center(pos);
                    alert('Success');


            }, function() {
                    alert('Section 3: The Geolocation service failed.');
            });
            } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            Alert('Section 2: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            }
```

**Result:**
Section 1: Pass
Section 2: Pass
Section 3: The Geolocation service failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so here is my guess as an answer.

Do you have location turned off in your browser? My browser asks me if I want to submit my position. You can try this code: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Another guess would be to adapt your code to this:

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  alert("My browser supports Geolocations");
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(alertPosition);
} else {
   alert("My browser doesn't support Geolocations");
}

function alertPosition(position) {
  alert("My Position is Lat:" + position.coords.latitude +
    ", Lng: " + position.coords.longitude);
}
```

But i think this won't work in the snippet because it's not your position but the position of the server the snippet is running on, and that won't probably tell you its position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution to get the client positions

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    alert('Your browser support this feature');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    alert('Your browser does not support this feature');
}
function showPosition(position) {
    alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "\nLongitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
}
```